# How to write Apex to query a related object based on if an other object meets a criteria without using a loop?

Tags: apex

Hello objective is the following:

Get all the records from objectA where their date is equal to today.
Update relatedRecords in objectB with values for each record of ObjectA that got queried.

How do I do this without using a for loop + query?

Some generic code:

```
List<Contract> contracts = new List<Contract>();
contracts = [Select Id, Name, etc from Contract where StartDate =: Date.Today()];

For each contract in contracts, query the related contact of the contract. 
And assign field values. Add that contact to a list then insert the list 
when all contacts are updated.
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Use maps to store and get the related records by a given key => Iterate through your list of contracts, update the objects stored in the maps => after the loop, update the records contained in the maps.

Comment: Going to have to use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You use a map, for loop, and query.

```
Map<Id, Contact> contactsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Contact>();
Contract[] contracts = [select CustomerSignedId, ... from Contract where ...];
for(Contract contractRecord: contracts) {
  Contact contactRecord = new Contact(Id = contractRecord.CustomerSignedId);
  // ...
  contactsToUpdate.put(contactRecord.Id, contactRecord);
}
update contactsToUpdate.values();
```